# Pubnub Socket.io - disconnect from a channel

Tags: javascript, socket.io, pubnub

Using Pubnub's Socket.io implementation, how does one disconnect from a channel (or at all)?

I set up my connection like this:

```
socket = io.connect "http://pubsub.pubnub.com",
  channel:       "some-channel"
  publish_key:   "..."
  subscribe_key: "..."
```

But when I try to disconnect like this (the way you do when using normal Socket.io):

```
socket.disconnect()
```

I get error messages like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Pubnub's Socket.io implementation. See the [issue on Github](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/issues/158). It has been fixed in version 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think correct syntax is :

```
socket.on( 'disconnect', function() {
    console.log('my connection dropped');
} );
```

https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/socket.io